# EXT Grid hangs on reload

Tags: gridview, extjs

Using an EXT Grid to display real-time data.  The grid is refreshed once a second.  It was scrolling to the top on every refresh until I overrode the scrollToTop function.

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.GridView, { 
    scrollToTop: Ext.emptyFn
});
```

However, it still hangs (prevents scrolling) for a non-trivial amount of time.  How can I get rid of the hang?

Comment: how many records are you loading each time? what browser and version of ExtJS?

Comment: Records: 400 rows, 15 columns.  Latest Production EXT (3.3 I think). Chrome browser

Comment: 400 Rows is a lot of data, if you inspect the response for the gridload in firebug, paste it into a text file and see how big the size of that file is? I would try to cut down the number of rows you're loading if possible

Comment: 40k.    That's not a lot of data.

Comment: are you running the app locally?

Comment: just as a side note, 40k _isn't_ a lot of data to transfer relatively, but ExtJS has to parse and format the rows for the grid which is probably what is causing it to hang, I had a similar situation where a developer had loaded around 10,000 records in a data store, this made the application hang for around 6-8 seconds everytime

Comment: I think there's a big difference though between 400 rows and 10,000 rows.  If you look at some of the jQuery grids this isn't an issue, even for 10,000 rows.

Comment: how many fields are you dealing with?  There is a big difference between trying to render 400 rows of 1 column and 400 rows with 20 columns!  Have you done any javascript profiling on the code to see where the bottleneck is?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the grid will take *some* non-trivial amount of time to render 400 rows of data. You can try to reduce the rendering workload by making the grid markup as light as possible (no fancy renderers etc.), but your best bet may be to either wait for [ExtJS version 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs4-preview/) (which reputedly offers [a huge boost to grid performance](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs4-preview/#components)), or if you are willing to use plugins, have a look at [Ext.ux.Livegrid](http://www.ext-livegrid.com/).

Answer (score 0):

just like this:

```
function OrderInfoLoad() {
    var scrollTop = Efs.getExt("ordergrid").getView().scroller.dom.scrollTop;
    var scrollHeight = Efs.getExt("ordergrid").getView().scroller.dom.scrollHeight;
    Efs.Common.ajax("../sysadmin/baseRefWeb.aspx?method=CarManage_Order&pid=0", "", function (succ, response, options) {
        if (succ) { // 是否成功
            var xmlReturnDoc = response.responseXML;
            Efs.getExt("ordergrid").getStore().loadData(xmlReturnDoc);
            Efs.getExt("ordergrid").getView().scroller.dom.scrollTop = scrollTop
                        + (scrollTop == 0
                                ? 0
                                : Efs.getExt("ordergrid").getView().scroller.dom.scrollHeight
                                        - scrollHeight);
        }

    });
}
```

you should remember the scroll and reload it.